# I cannot update my SQL database using my Javafx table

Tags: java, sql, mysql, javafx

The goal was to change the values in my SQL table using my JavaFX table. The reading works fine, only the inserting is missing.

```
private void getQuery() {
    if (aktualisieren == false) {

        query = "INSERT INTO tabelle (Verein, Spiele, Siege, Niederlagen, Unentschieden, Tore, Gegentore, Tordifferenz, Punkte) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    }else{
        query = "UPDATE `tabelle` SET "
                    + "`Verein`=?,"
                    + "`Spiele`=?,"
                    + "`Siege`=?,"
                    + "`Niederlagen`=?,"
                    + "`Unentschieden`=?,"
                    + "`Tore`=?,"
                    + "`Gegentore`=?,"
                    + "`Tordifferenz`=?,"
                    + "`Punkte`=?";

    }
}
```

```
private void insert() {

    try {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement((query));
        preparedStatement.setString(1, vereinFid.getText());
        preparedStatement.setString(1, spieleFid.getText());
        preparedStatement.setString(1, siegeFid.getText());
        preparedStatement.setString(1, niederlagenFid.getText());
        preparedStatement.setString(1, unentschiedenFid.getText());
        preparedStatement.setString(1, toreFid.getText());
        preparedStatement.setString(1, gegentoreFid.getText());
        preparedStatement.setString(1, punkteFid.getText());

    } catch (SQLException exception) {
           Logger.getLogger(AddTabelleController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, exception);
    }

}
```

```
@FXML
void speichern(MouseEvent event) {

    connection = DbVerbindung.getConnect();
    String Verein = vereinFid.getText();
    String Spiele = spieleFid.getText();
    String Siege = siegeFid.getText();
    String Niederlagen = spieleFid.getText();
    String Unentschieden = unentschiedenFid.getText();
    String Tore = toreFid.getText();
    String Gegentore = gegentoreFid.getText();
    String Punkte = punkteFid.getText();

    if (Verein.isEmpty() | Spiele.isEmpty()| Siege.isEmpty()| Niederlagen.isEmpty()| Unentschieden.isEmpty()| Tore.isEmpty()| Gegentore.isEmpty()| Punkte.isEmpty())
    {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Bitte füllen sie die Daten aus");
        alert.showAndWait();

    }else{
        getQuery();
        insert();
        leeren();
    }

}
```

I read that I should add the question marks and reduce the quotes, but it still doesn't work.
Problem with this is that I don't get an error message from IntelliJ, so I don't know what the issue is.
[This is what my SQL table looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyL1Y.png)
[I get this message from SQL when I run my program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqV6Q.png)

Comment: What error message do you get if you execute the above queries?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not get an error message, the program runs without problems, only the values in the database do not change. I have added the query.

Comment: In your code you are only preparing the query. You should also execute it.

Comment: I wanted to avoid inserting the whole code and therefore only inserted the supposedly relevant things. I have added the execution.

Comment: Are you using global or at least class-wide variables, like query?

Comment: I'm using class-wide variables.

Comment: Watch  your [naming](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions) and please update your question to show you're now calling `executeUpdate`. Close the `Statement` too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see several problems in the code in your question. Your use of [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) is wrong. You can't use the same index for each invocation of method [setString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,java.lang.String)). Also, according to the image you posted, some of the columns in database table `tabelle` have `int` data type and so method `setString` is probably not appropriate. You should also use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure that you close the `PreparedStatement`. Also, the database will only be updated if you call method [executeUpdate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()). Consider the following: (Note that your code is not assigning a value to column `Tordifferenz` which will cause an error.)

```java
private void insert() {
    try (preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
        preparedStatement.setString(1, vereinFid.getText());
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(spieleFid.getText()));
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(siegeFid.getText()));
        preparedStatement.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(niederlagenFid.getText()));
        preparedStatement.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(unentschiedenFid.getText()));
        preparedStatement.setInt(6, Integer.parseInt(toreFid.getText()));
        preparedStatement.setInt(7, Integer.parseInt(gegentoreFid.getText()));
        preparedStatement.setInt(8, Integer.parseInt(punkteFid.getText()));
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException exception) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddTabelleController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, exception);
    }
}
```

Do you realize that your [SQL] UPDATE will update all rows in `tabelle` since it contains no WHERE clause?

In method `speichern` you are using [bitwise OR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) instead of [logical OR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

```java
if (Verein.isEmpty()        ||
    Spiele.isEmpty()        ||
    Siege.isEmpty()         ||
    Niederlagen.isEmpty()   ||
    Unentschieden.isEmpty() ||
    Tore.isEmpty()          ||
    Gegentore.isEmpty()     ||
    Punkte.isEmpty())
```

Comment: Thank u very much. The missing execute and the "where" part was the problem.